# Jquery growing and shrinking textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a textarea grow when you press enter and shrink when you finish deleting a line. In other words, the textarea remains just big enough to contain the text inside of it, while the text is being edited.

Unless anyone knows a better way to do this, right now I'm doing it with jquery detecting keypresses. It's fairly easy to make the textarea larger on an enter press, but I'm at a loss as to how to make it shrink when you delete a carriage return.

How do you (preferably with jquery) detect when a carriage return is deleted in a textarea?

Comment: This is an opinion, but it's often frustrating to me when things change size automatically if it is not done right.

Comment: As long as it's a text-area, this effect can be helpful. I don't like it on what appeared to be single line text inputs, though. I have a couple instances of that and hitting enter to submit the form just adds a carriage return.

Comment: @Tom Hubbard: I'm essentially working with a spreadsheet, and the textarea is a cell, so I think that in this case it's fairly justified. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the TextArea resizer plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer

Comment: That's a little different from what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var computedElement = window.getComputedStyle($(element)[0]),
        paddingTop = parseInt(computedElement.paddingTop),
        paddingBottom = parseInt(computedElement.paddingBottom),
        borderBottom = parseInt(computedElement.borderBottom),
        borderTop = parseInt(computedElement.borderTop),
        lineHeight = parseInt(computedElement.lineHeight),
        outerHeight = paddingBottom + paddingTop + borderTop + borderBottom;

        var resize = function() {
          //height:auto resets the height to row=1 to get the scrollHeight without white space
          $(element).css('height', 'auto');
          $(element).height($(element)[0].scrollHeight - outerHeight);
        }

        //first resize to set the existing text
        $timeout(function(){
          if($(element).val().length) {
            resize();
          }
        });

        //resize on keyup and keydown 
        $(element).on('keydown keyup', function() {
          $timeout(function(){
            resize();
          });
        });
```