# Form input field grows with overflowing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery growing and shrinking textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988876/jquery-growing-and-shrinking-textarea)

I want to achieve an effect where a text `<input>` will grow vertically when the text overflows. So instead of the beginning text being scrolled off, a new line starts, and the `<input>` grows vertically.

How could I achieve this using Javascript/jQuery/CSS/HTML/etc?

Comment: The correct input to use is a textarea not text. Then this question covers the same ground: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988876/jquery-growing-and-shrinking-textarea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can use an autogrowing `textarea` styled as an `input` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcHnV/)

```
textarea {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    resize: none;
}​
```

There are numerous plugins exists to achieve the same effect - I used [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize) for the demo.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesn't grow, a scroll bar just appears, even with the .autosize(). The textarea is dynamically inserted if that makes a difference, and I rebind the .autosize() after the insertion, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: works for me even with dynamic textarea - http://jsfiddle.net/bcHnV/1/ have you included jquery and the plugin?

Comment: this is what happens http://jsfiddle.net/bcHnV/2/

Comment: still OK for me.. what browser are you in?

Comment: hm thats weird. Didn't work before.

Comment: maybe its because I'm using twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 3):

A pure Javascript way:

```
<textarea onkeyup="while(this.scrollTop > 0) {this.rows++;}"></textarea>
```